# Does all pizza have butter?

Tags: butter, pizza

Does pizza normally get made with Butter?

For example, if someone is allergic... or has an intolerance, to butter do they need to avoid pizza?

What about individual pizza companies like Pizza hut, Domino's, Jets Pizza and so forth?

Comment: Just to be careful I have to point this out: If someone's allergic to butter it stands to reason they would also be allergic to cheese. So if it's an overall dairy allergy then probably pizza should be avoided altogether.

Comment: @DaveKaye often people with lactose intolerance have an easier time digesting cultured dairy products like cheese, vs something like butter which has not undergone any microbial processes.

Of course, I make all my pizzas with EVOO.

Comment: @alexw - I believe butter is usually much more lactose-free than cheese, most of the lactose is left behind in the buttermilk even if one is not making cultured butter.  Butter is almost pure fat, there's not much sugar left behind to begin with and it is the sugar that culturing affects.  Also, I think almost all cheeses contain butterfats, it is part of what becomes the cheese curds, so I don't think someone who cannot have butter at all can have cheese for that reason.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Very, very few pizzas are made with butter.  There is no way to make a universal statement, but butter is a rare.  Olive oil would be more likely.

Many pizza doughs are fat-free, including the traditional pizza di napoli; New York style generally contains olive oil.

It is rare for any traditional toppings to contain butter.   Some individual cooks might saute vegetables in butter, but even then, olive oil more common.

As for particular restaurant chains, you would need to check their nutrition information sites.

---

Note:  as Derobert points out, some deep dish Chicago style pizzas may contain butter in the crust.

Comment: It should be pointed out that deep-dish/Chicago-style pizza does contain butter in the crust. And the sauce.

Comment: @derobert The horror.   It seems some such recipes do contain butter.   But I am in the "Chicago pizza" is a casserole, not a pizza faction.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Sounds like US Congress, though I see the comparison quite clearly.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks for all of the other answers as well. I know someone who is allergic to butter and wasn't able to find any really solid results online.

Comment: There seem to even be pizza dough recipes around that contain.... egg. Not common, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of butter in pizza.
[image: Pizza Dough Formulas]

Answer (score 0):

As @saj12saj says, very few pizza recipes use butter. As for chain restaurants most publish their ingredients, so you can probably find that information on their websites. I'd be surprised though, most chains prefer to use butter substitutes to lower their costs.